# Barcode Help! iOS

Tags: ios, generator, barcode

I would like to create an application which allows information to be retrieved from the database, and the direct back to the iPhone application and auto generate a barcode out of the number stored in the database.

For example, Member A's barcode number(1000001) is stored in the database and I would like to retrieve this piece of information from the database, generate 1000001 as a barcode in my application and reflect on it. Whereas Member B would have a barcode number of 1000002. Every member has a unique set of number. Is it possible for me to do that? If so, how can i do?

Can Cocoatouch barcode does this job? As I have downloaded the project of the cocoatouch barcode but i do not know where to implement it at.

Comment: What kind of barcode do you want to generate?  There are many kinds.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014670/barcode-generator-xcode. Reposting a question that didn't get an answer isn't gonna get you an answer.